# Android Game Float-Coordinates query with if imprecise

Tags: java

//SOLVED!!!!

Hello i have a problem with my Android Game,
i want to query the char coordinates with the end of the map coordinates but when i'm starting
the game and move the character to the end this is very impresice, but it works.
i think the problem is that the coordinates from character and end are floats but i don't know how i can this make better work this is my actuel code:

```
if((int)charX == (int)endMapX && (int)charY == (int)endMapY){
        stop();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                charEndingMapListener.charEndingMap();
            }
        });

    }
```

i hope you can help me :)
sry for my bad englisch 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to have understood your problem and if it's really related to the casting. You can try to change your if condition with something like this and see if it works better for you:

```
if(charX >= endMapX && charY >= endMapY){
   charX = endMapX;
   charY = endMapY;
   //your code there...
```

Comment: thank you ! now its a litte bit better but the problem here is that when i'm going >x and >y it pulls the character automatically to the end. i think i can resolve the problem when define a span for the end, but how?